# Passing Variables through Colorbox Callbacks

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a series of tooltips that are firing in sequence on a map.  When a user clicks on the area of the map a colorbox pops-up with information about the location.

I want to grab the div ID of the Tooltip that is active when I open the colorbox and store it as a variable.  Then on close, I want to reactivate the tooltips with that variable.  I can't seem to figure out a way to pass the variable from one call back to the next.  Here's my code:

```
$(".city").colorbox({
    inline:true, 
    width:"390px", 
    opacity: .2,

    onOpen: function(){var selected = $('.qtip').attr('id');},
    onClosed: function(){$(selected).qtip();}
    });
```

Is this even possible?  I tried just using alert(selected) and it didn't seem to be working.

Comment: Declaring your `selected` var as global (outside of any function) might be a good start. When you try to access it in another function having it declared inside a limited function scope as you're doing, it'll return an undefined variable error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** that the `click` to open the colorbox is done on the same element that has the qTip plugin, and that the elements class is `.city`:

**JQUERY**

```
$(".city").bind("click", function() {

  // store the jQuery object of the clicked element
  var $obj = $(this);

  // hide the tooltip
  $obj.qtip("hide");

  // call the colorbox
  $obj.colorbox({
    inline   : true, 
    width    : "390px", 
    opacity  : .2,
    onClosed : function(){
      // call the tooltip
      $obj.qtip("show");
    }
  });

});
```

Something along this line should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you ought steer clear of using variables as the mechanism of communication. A better pattern for this would be pub/sub, where in the events that happen "within" a colorbox popup publish an event that is consumed by a function with its own scope and internals.  There are many pub/subs out there for JS/JQuery projects. a simple one is Ben Alman's Tiny Pub/Sub.
https://gist.github.com/661855